# How to change a URL parameter on a link that has # as href and is submitted inside a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, url-parameters

I'm working on a drupal module and it gets images from an API, adds selectable search-filters and generates pagination. If I go to e.g. the 7th pagination page and add a filter that only spans 3 pages it will result in not showing anything at all.

Solution: on upon adding a filter, go back to the 1st page. Now is my problem that that page is an url parameter and the links made by the filter are set to `href='#'` so basically this page yes.

So I try to debug the javascript that handles the on click:

```
$('#blabla .filter-url').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var link = $(e.currentTarget);
    console.log(link);
    var filter_key = link.data('filter-key');
    var filter_value = link.data('filter-value');
    // var active = link.hasClass('active');

    var filters_input = $('#blabla input[name="filters"]');

    var current_filters = JSON.parse(filters_input.val() || '{}');
    current_filters.filters = current_filters.filters || [];

    var exists = ($.grep(current_filters.filters, function(e, i){
        return e.key == filter_key;
    }).length);
    if (exists) {
         //Remove current filter from list
        current_filters.filters = $.grep(current_filters.filters, function(e, i){
            return e.key != filter_key;
        });
        link.removeClass('active');
    }

    // Add current filter to list
    current_filters.filters.push({
        key: filter_key,
        value: filter_value,
    });
    link.addClass('active');

    filters_input.val(JSON.stringify(current_filters));
    $('#formname').submit();
});
```

the link object:

[image: link object]

The link object has a `{0, context and length}` object in which both `0` and `context` contain multiple instances of the url, which one should I edit?

I just want to manipulate the URL / get parameter `page=xxx` to be `page=0`, so it goes back to the 1st page. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was searching in the wrong place. At the end of the onclick-function it submits the form. I had to change the `action` of this form like this:

```
var old_form_action = $('#formname').attr('action');
var new_form_action = old_form_action.replace(/(page=)[^\&]+/, '$1' + '0');
$('#formname').attr('action', new_form_action);
```